# Access Union Types outside of declaring module in Elm

Tags: elm

Given

```
--module 1
module Module1 exposing (Message) where

type Message
  = Test String
  | Error Int


--module 2
module Module2 exposing (sayTest, sayError) where

import Module1 exposing (Message)

sayTest : String -> Message
sayTest msg =
  Test msg  --error

sayError : Int -> Message
sayError code =
  Error code --error


processMessage : Message -> String
processMessage msg ->
  case msg of
    Test s -> s
    Error i -> toString i
```

How do I access `Test` and `Error` from module 2?

At the moment, I have to create functions in module 1 which when called will create the instances needed but as the list is getting longer, this is becoming impractical.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can expose all type constructors for an exported type like this:

```elm
module Module1 (Message (..)) where
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to export only a few type constructors, you can call them out individually:

```elm
module Module1 (Message (Test, Error)) where

type Message
  = Test String
  | Error Int
  | Foo String
  | Bar
```

In the above code, the Foo and Bar constructors remain private to the module.

Comment: Save yourself the pain of updating the export statement when you add a new constructor by using `module Message1 (Message (..)) where`...

Comment: Thanks for the reminder grumpyjames. I've amended my answer to include the `..` variation