# Cannot expose UnionType

Tags: elm, union-types

I have two elm modules trying to share a union type as I try to refactor my app as described here https://www.elm-tutorial.org/en-v01/02-elm-arch/07-composing-2.html but I keep getting

> does not expose

even though I have tried to model it as in https://github.com/elm/elm-lang.org/issues/523

Module 1

```
module Module1 exposing ( OneMsg(..), Model, view, [etc.] )

...

type OneMsg
    = Name String 

...
```

Module 2

```
module Module2 exposing(..)

import Module1 exposing(OneMsg(..))


type Msg
    = UrlChange Navigation.Location 
    | ...
    | Module1Msg Module1.OneMsg

...

Html.map Module1.OneMsg (Module1.view model)

...
```

Getting this error

```
   -- NAMING ERROR ---------------------------------------------- ././view/View.elm

   Cannot find variable `Module1.OneMsg`.

   74|                     Html.map Module1.OneMsg (Module1.view model)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   `Module1` does not expose `OneMsg`.
```

Only thing I found here is an old questions which seems to be the same event though an old syntax:
[Access Union Types outside of declaring module in Elm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912005/access-union-types-outside-of-declaring-module-in-elm)

In case relevant I use elm 0.18.0.

Bet I just missed something. Can any one spot the problem?

Comment: Could you please show the type definition of `OneMsg`?

Comment: It was there, I had just renamed it in order to separate the issue and forgot one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Module1.OneMsg` is a type. `Html.map` expects a function as its first parameter. The way you typically bubble up messages would be something like this (in `Module2`):

```
type Module2Msg
    = ...
    | Module1Msg Module1.OneMsg
```

And then you could use it like this in `Module2`:

```
Html.map Module1Msg (Module1.view model)
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the "main" Msg I have. Edited the question to include this.

Comment: Sorry, I do not reuse the name. I guess it would be rather stupid to do so. It was a simple copy-paste miss.

Comment: In that case you should be fine with `Html.map Module1Msg (Module1.view model)` (answer updated)

Comment: Now I see it. Html.map `Module1.OneMsg (Module1.view model)` vs `Html.map Module1Msg (Module1.view model)`. Thanks.